# I can not visit localhost with apache on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, apache

The Chrome alert me

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost

But my apache still running:

```
  501 80299 71841   0  2:35PM ttys003    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

I paste some piece of important apache configuration , please help me. Thanks.

**http.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/usr" Listen 80

ServerAdmin you@example.com

DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"

<Directory />   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all </Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Actually I don't know what file I need to show you.

If you need more configuration file detail, please tell me. I will paste later.

Comment: Let us help you by having a read at the [about] and [help] and explaining 1. how you started apache or installed it in the first place. 2. Where you are stuck precisely. Out of the box, no mac can connect to localhost in Chrome (or any other browser for that matter) so it's hard for us to guess what you have set up here.

Comment: @bmike, I update my question, Please unhold my question, Thanks

Comment: Apache comes with the base OS X and there really isn't a way to uninstall. What actually are you tying to do?

Comment: @bmike, No, I just want to make my apache come back. I modify some configuration, but now I can not visit localhost. I update my question again, please help me.

Comment: Is Apache even running? What does `ps -ef | grep httpd` return?

Comment: 501 80299 71841   0  2:35PM ttys003    0:00.00 grep httpd

Comment: That `ps` output doesn't show apache running, it shows grep running (and searching for httpd). You may just need to start it; see instructions in [this superuser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/455505/how-do-i-start-apache-in-osx-mountain-lion/456151#456151).

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

That should start your standard apache server software as well as edit the system startup files to cause it to start at boot. Replace start with stop to reverse that change. Your grep shows that httpd is not actually running and there's just the grep process active. You may need to look at the logs if after asking apachectl to start things up, the httpd process doesn't stay running (or even start in the first place).